# Optimization problem in Python. Dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have the following task.

> There is a list of segments: list[int]. All these segments must be involved. We have the length of the rope and infinite number of ropes. when we make combinations, most often there is a remainder. For example, the length of the rope is 10000, and the segments are [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1500] and here we have a remainder of 500. And when there are more segments, we will use several ropes and each will have a remainder, and this is what needs to be minimized.

Here's the code:

```
def max_sum_sequence(arr, l) -> tuple:
    n = len(arr)
    dp = [0] * (l + 1)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(l, arr[i] - 1, -1):
            dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - arr[i]] + arr[i])

    result = []
    current_sum = l
    if sum(arr) <= current_sum:
        return tuple(item for item in reversed(arr))

    for num in reversed(arr):
        if current_sum >= num and dp[current_sum - num] + num == dp[current_sum]:
            result.append(num)
            current_sum -= num
    return tuple(result)


def update_segments(arr: list, l: int) -> list[list[tuple[int], int]]:
    result: list[list[tuple[int], int]] = []
    while True:
        optimal_sequence: tuple[int] = max_sum_sequence(arr, l)
        remainder: int = length - sum(optimal_sequence)
        result.append([optimal_sequence, remainder])
        for item in optimal_sequence:
            arr.remove(item)
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    remainder_summary: int = 0
    print("Enter a length:")
    length: int = 12000
    segments = [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530,
                1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530,
                1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530,
                1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 3260, 3260, 3260, 3260, 3760, 3760, 1660, 1660,
                1660, 1660, 1660, 1660, 3650, 3650, 3650, 1970, 1970, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330,
                1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 2410, 2410, 1180, 1180, 1180, 1180, 550, 550, 550, 550]
    optimal_values: list = update_segments(segments, length)
    for item in optimal_values:
        print(f"{item[0]} - {item[1]}")
        remainder_summary += item[1]
    print(f"Final remainder = {remainder_summary}")
```

Output:

```
(550, 550, 550, 550, 1180, 1180, 1180, 2410, 1330, 1970) - 550

(1180, 2410, 1330, 1660, 1660, 3760) - 0

(1330, 3650, 3760, 3260) - 0

(1970, 3650, 1660, 1660, 1530, 1530) - 0

(1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330) - 30

(1330, 1330, 1660, 3260, 1530, 1530) - 1360

(1660, 3260, 3260) - 3820

(1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530) - 4350
```

For some reason, at iteration 7, the algorithm does not take segments that can be included in it in order to reduce the remainder. And this happens in all subsequent iterations.

What is the mistake?

upd 01.27.2024

```
def max_sum_sequence(arr, l) -> tuple:
    n = len(arr)
    dp = [0] * (l + 1)
    choices = [[] for _ in range(l + 1)]

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(l, arr[i] - 1, -1):
            if dp[j] < dp[j - arr[i]] + arr[i]:
                dp[j] = dp[j - arr[i]] + arr[i]
                choices[j] = choices[j - arr[i]] + [arr[i]]

    return tuple(choices[l])

def update_segments(arr: list, l: int) -> list[list[tuple[int], int]]:
    result: list[list[tuple[int], int]] = []
    while True:
        optimal_sequence: tuple[int] = max_sum_sequence(arr, l)
        remainder: int = l - sum(optimal_sequence)
        result.append([optimal_sequence, remainder])
        for item in optimal_sequence:
            arr.remove(item)
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return result


def get_optimal(length: int, segments: list[list[int,int]) -> list[list[tuple[int], int]]:
    length: int = length
    segments: list[int] = modify_segments_list(segments)
    optimal_values: list[list[tuple[int], int]] = update_segments(segments, length)
    return optimal_values
```

There is output of this problem

```
|3840--2605--2605--2940| ==> 10
|1840--1840--2430--2940--2940| ==> 10
|1840--1840--2430--2940--2940| ==> 10
|1840--1840--2430--2940--2940| ==> 10
|2430--2940--2840--3780| ==> 10
|5365--2840--3780| ==> 15
|1840--3370--3370--3370| ==> 50
|5020--3370--3545| ==> 65
|1840--2840--3545--3545| ==> 230
|3840--5020--2840| ==> 300
|3840--3840--3840| ==> 480
|3840--3780--3780| ==> 600
|2840--2840--2840--2840| ==> 640
|3780--3780--3545| ==> 895
```

Comment: You are not explaining at all what do you mean by "cost of ropes". Is it the residual after cutting the rope in "segments"?

Comment: yes, I need the residue from all the ropes to be minimal

Comment: Ok, but all your segments do not add up to an integer multiple of 12000. There is 1890 remaining at minimum, no matter what you do, so maybe a better objective is for the remainders to be as long as possible, so they can be reutilized in future cuts. So you should start with x 12000 long ropes, more a set of older remains. Then it would be a better objective something like "the remains should be  pieces whose length has high probability of occurrence", rather than minimum pieces, so they can be used without cutting, or should be pieces whose length facilitates future cuts in some way.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connect-n-ropes-minimum-cost/) the problem you are trying to solve? If not, could you provide a link to a statement of the problem?

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you could explain your problem in more detail. I know that people on StackOverflow often comment "show us your code!!" but really, explaining the problem is more important than your code. The only thing we know is that you have a rope and "segments" and that some things have a cost. This is all a lot less explicit than you might think. What is a segment? Is it a pair of numbers [a, b] with a < b ? Is it just one length l > 0 ? We don't know. Please tell us more.

Comment: Frank, you have asked for our help but you refuse to answer our questions. Why?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't answer.
There is a list of segments: list[int]. All these segments must be involved. We have the length of the rope and infinite number of ropes.
when we make combinations, most often there is a remainder.
For example, the length of the rope is 10000, and the segments are [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1500] and here we have a remainder of 500.
And when there are more segments, we will use several ropes and each will have a remainder, and this is what needs to be minimized.
I updated the question, you can see what I came up with

Comment: Cary Swoveland, no, I think these are different problems

Comment: This looks like a 1D cutting stock problem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) , but I've never seen it explained in such a convoluted manner.

Comment: Nelewout, ahaha, thanks :)

Comment: Frank, @Nelewout has identified your problem as a cutting stock problem, the objective being to minimize the number of ropes from which all segments are cut. That's equivalent, however, to minimizing the total wastage since the total length of all segments plus the wastage equals the length of each rope times the number of ropes required. As shown at the Wiki link this is a difficult problem that can be solved by modelling it as a linear program with binary-value variables (e.g., xij = 1 if segment i is cut from rope j, = 0 otherwise). You therefore will not find a simpler algorithm.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, thanks, I get it. Try to realise

Comment: @FrankDelan [this notebook](https://alns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/cutting_stock_problem.html) might be helpful for you. Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a "greedy" algorithm as i believe that this is a better (more optimal) approach to the problem.

This basically means:

- selecting the largest segments first.
- do this repeatedly until all the segments are used.

So this is my solution:

```py
segments = [
    1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 
    1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 
    1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 
    1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 
    1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 
    3260, 3260, 3260, 3260, 3760, 3760, 1660, 1660, 1660, 1660, 1660, 1660, 
    3650, 3650, 3650, 1970, 1970, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 
    1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 2410, 2410, 1180, 1180, 1180, 
    1180, 550, 550, 550, 550]


ropes = 12000
total_remaining_rope = 0

ordered_segments = sorted(segments, reverse=True)

while len(ordered_segments) > 0:
    # Initialize the list for selected segments
    selected_segments = []

    # Initialize the remaining rope length
    remaining_rope = ropes

    # Loop through the segments
    for segment in ordered_segments:
        if segment <= remaining_rope:
            # If the segment fits, add it to the selected list 
            selected_segments.append(segment)
            # and reduce the remaining rope length
            remaining_rope -= segment
    
    # Output the selected segments
    print("Selected segments:", selected_segments, 
        "Remaining rope length:", remaining_rope)
    
    total_remaining_rope += remaining_rope

    # remove items from selected_segments
    for segment in selected_segments:
        ordered_segments.remove(segment)

print('--------------------------------------')
print('the total remaining rope:', total_remaining_rope)
```

And this is the result:

```
Selected segments: [3760, 3760, 3650, 550] Remaining rope length: 280
Selected segments: [3650, 3650, 3260, 1330] Remaining rope length: 110
Selected segments: [3260, 3260, 3260, 1970] Remaining rope length: 250
Selected segments: [2410, 2410, 1970, 1660, 1660, 1660] Remaining rope length: 230
Selected segments: [1660, 1660, 1660, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 550] Remaining rope length: 350
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1180] Remaining rope length: 110
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1180] Remaining rope length: 110
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1180] Remaining rope length: 110
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1180] Remaining rope length: 110
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 550, 550] Remaining rope length: 190
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530] Remaining rope length: 1290
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530] Remaining rope length: 1290
Selected segments: [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530] Remaining rope length: 1290
Selected segments: [1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330, 1330] Remaining rope length: 30
Selected segments: [1330, 1330, 1330, 1330] Remaining rope length: 6680
--------------------------------------
the total remaining rope: 12430
```

You can even see hope much rope is left over at the end !

Comment: I confess that I don't know what "...find such combinations of segments that minimize the cost of ropes." means, but it does suggest that the OP is looking for an optimal solution, not a "more optimal" solution, whatever that means.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree and this also suggests a possible confusion between "optimal solution" (a solution for which the cost is minimum) and "optimal algorithm" (is that an algorithm that minimises its own time of execution or an algorithm that finds an optimal solution?)

Comment: @Stef,  I kind of agree with you both.  I just answered the question because it is quite an interesting problem. I can see why the OP took that approach, but it gets messy that way. The OP made a good attempt, but that method just introduces a lot more variables.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in considering this issue.
Unfortunately, the greedy algorithm is not suitable and I had to reconsider the approach.
Let's look at two options. In the first case, to obtain the segments, we needed 3 ropes and the resulting residues were [250, 150, 125], and in the second it turned out to be [10, 10, 500]. In my situation, it’s better when one large piece remains because it can be reused. And several medium ropes are not always suitable.

Comment: I updated the question, you can see what I came up with

Comment: @FrankDelan, comparing the algo's, we observe that the greedy algo has the smallest loss (1210 vs 3325). And it is also computationally more efficient. Is it the case that you are asserting that it is less efficient for a smaller number of ropes (i.e. smaller array) or on what basis is it unsuitable ?

Comment: D.L, your loss in not 1210. "All these segments must be involved" but in your way only 31/104

Comment: @FrankDelan,  yes,  you are correct. thank you for pointing this out.  I changed the code (how the segments are removed) to use all the pieces. I have also posted the new result, which has a bigger loss.  Very interesting.

Comment: @D.L, first of all, I also thought about the greedy algorithm. But after implementation I realized that the main disadvantage is that there are many segments of short length left

Comment: @FrankDelan,  this is correct. However, the left over lengths are a function of the mathematics. I have not come across a better algo. Whilst the algo in the question is logical, it is not clear that it would produce a better outcome. Also, i tested for speed (just out of interest) and the greedy algo is fast.